# Unreadable styling for highlighted tags on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

When highlighted because the mouse moves over them, the “status-bydesign” tag and some others turn into a weird and unreadable combination of colours: black text on maroon background. Here's an example:

> [image: Screenshot demonstrating the issue]

As such, I find it unreadable.

Comment: Very good point. I would consider black on dark burnt orange to be a UI disaster. The UI team could simply add `color: #FFFFFF` or even an orange of the same color as the star next to the text (roughly #B14C45) to the style rules for that selector to improve readability. The rest of the site is graphically quite good, so I'm sure this was just someone's tiny oversight.

Comment: I think it's simple oversight, but that hasn't been picked up (or commented on) in almost a week. This meta seems very slow...

Answer (score 1):

I can read it, and it doesn't really bother me; but I suppose a lighter red would be a small improvement.

Comment: It may depend on screen calibration. I am not colourblind, and I cannot read it without getting my eyes very close to decipher it. The colors are just two close.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how meta works, and this bug report hasn't gathered a lot of interest. I wonder if I'm supposed to write an answer here, saying

***yes, please fix it***

so that people can upvote it and the bugfix will come :)
I'll make it community wiki, so people can edit/remove it if that was not the right thing to do!

Comment: People should upvote the question. Which I've done.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this got fixed at some point in the last, uh, 3 years:

[image]

Better late than never, right? :)