# Tag text appears outside box in Firefox 3.0

Tags: bug, status-declined

The screenshot in [FX_’s question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/572/unreadable-styling-for-highlighted-tags-on-meta) confirmed my suspicion that tags do not appear properly in my browser.  I’m using Firefox 3.0.18 (OK, I’m a Luddite) and the text appears underneath the box instead of in it, thus:

> [image: Screenshot showing tags]

I’m assuming this is a feature of Firefox.  Not clamouring for a fix, but I thought I should at least mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We generally only support the latest release + the previous release of any given browser.

For Firefox this would be 3.5 and 3.6 -- is there any reason you must be 3 versions behind?

Comment: Is there any reason Mozilla must make their software bigger and slower and expect me to accept it as an improvement?

Comment: @brian 3.6 is *dramatically* faster at JavaScript

Comment: That may be, but the world seems to be passing Firefox by at this point, and it's in danger of getting eclipsed (if not back-watered) by Chrome and Safari (and who knows what IE 9 portends?) While I still develop with it first (nothing beats Firebug, for my money), I'm not impressed with its support for HTML 5, particularly the Canvas element. I had hoped that would change with 4, but so far the betas I've downloaded have shown no improvement. Well, since they *are* betas, I can hold out hope for a change in the final release version ...

Comment: "who knows what IE 9 portends": I don't think IE has ever portended anything in its life. IE 9 is a catch-up to browsers that actually display pages properly (and have done for some time), after all.